# Putting Analytic function interms of z from x,y

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity, analytic-functions

I stuck at last step. Please help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)